# error in compiled .ts with tsc compiler in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

there is a duplicate identifier error in .js tsc compiled code in VS code here is my .ts file I'm using VS code 0.5 and typescript 1.5.3,There is error in line `exports.User = User` and its complaining about duplicate:

```
import store = require("store/mongo")
export class User {
    public connectionId: string;
    public telegram_user: telegram.User;

    addToPoolDb(next): void {
        store.addToPoolDb(this, function(err) {
            next(err);
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the output :

```
var store = require("store/mongo");
var User = (function () {
    function User() {
    }

    User.prototype.addToPoolDb = function (next) {
        store.addToPoolDb(this, function (err) {
            next(err);
        });
    };
    return User;
})();
exports.User = User;
```

Comment: Do you have a namespace around the code shown?

Comment: I think the compiler is lost between your class `User` and `telegram.User` (and i don't see its `require('telegram')`).